# onActivityResult not wait results

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-studio

I have this code:

in class MainActivity when SettingButton is pressed:

```
static final int DUMP_REQUEST = 1;

public void onSettingButtonClick(View button)
{
    //call options menu activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OptionsMenuActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, DUMP_REQUEST);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == DUMP_REQUEST)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Log.e("onActivityResult", "resultOK");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("onActivityResult", "result_not_Ok");
        }
    }
}
```

in class OptionsMenuActivity when SaveButton is pressed:

```
public void onSaveButtonClicked(View v)
{
    String dumpDb="true";
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("DUMP", dumpDb);

    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

When I press SettingButton, *OptionsMenuActivity* starts, and immediately appears the Log:

```
E/onActivityResult﹕ result_not_Ok
```

When I click the SaveButton, *OptionsMenuActivity* is closed and *MainActivity* runs.

/--/

My problem is that *onActivityResult()* not waits for the result until I press *SaveButton*, and **never resultCode == RESULT_OK**, so never I can do my stuff depending on *OptionsMenuActivity* state

Comment: Include your manifest declaration of activities in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your OptionsMenuActivity has in manifest launchmode equal to singletask? This is an excerpt from startActivityForResults doc:

> For example, if the activity you are launching uses the singleTask launch mode, it will not run in your task and thus you will immediately receive a cancel result.